# sending out a mass email to all customers

Tags: email

i am in the process of transfering all my customers over form my old site to my new magento site, i have been told that everythign will transfer but the passwords. So i want to send out a mass email to all my customers asking them to follow a link and rest their passwords.

How can i do this as i dont want to have to go into everyone customer profile and send them one that way as i have over 2000 customers??

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is an actual way to retrieve passwords. You can use an observer on the "customer login" action, and check against their old password, if it matches, then you update their Magento password accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the format of the old passwords are, you can use them. I implemented a method to use PBKDF2 for ones shop, but you can use whatever hashing algorithm you want.

You just have to check against the new password:

https://github.com/ikonoshirt/pbkdf2

Beside this, I recommend to use a tool like mailchimp, cleverreach or whatever newsletter service fits you. If you do something wrong (and there is a lot which can be done wrong), you are blacklisted and then your order, invoice and shipping mails are sent to spam.